# How to remove the space on top of Tabs.TabPane of Ant Design?

Tags: antd

There is always a space on top of each TabPane, can anybody help to let me know I can remove it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite ant element's style. If there is some margin you should find class of this element, try to change it in inspector.

Then if everythink look good, you should rewrite it like `.ant-class-name{ margin: 0 //or other }`

Comment: I added a new class to overwrite the the default css and it works. thanks.

Comment: @pingcheng, you're welcome. Is it mean that you can turn answer as correct?